# Magento 2 - Get Attribute Set by ID?

Tags: magento2, blocks, template, phtml, attribute-set

Is there a way **from a phtml file to get the attributes of an attribute set given the set id**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to create a module for this.

So basically, you first need to find out which block renders your phtml file.

Once you've found out, you need to create `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\<Module>\Block\<Path>\<To>\<Block>"
                type="Vendor\Module\Block\<Path>\<To>\<Block>"/>
</config>
```

In this file you need to replace `Magento\<Module>\Block\<Path>\<To>\<Block>` with the path to the block rendering the template. Don't forget to replace `<Path>\<To>\<Block>` in the `type` attribute too.

Then in `app/code/Vendor/Module/Block/<Path>/<To>/<Block>` :

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Block\<Path>/<To>;

class <Block> extends \Magento\<Module>\Block\<Path>\<To>\<Block>
{

    protected $_productAttributeManagementInterface;

    public __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductAttributeManagementInterface $productAttributeManagementInterface
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->_productAttributeManagementInterface= $productAttributeManagementInterface;
        ...
    }

    public function getAttributes($id)
    {
        $attributes = $this->_productAttributeManagementInterface->getAttributes($id);
        return $attributes ;
    }
}
```

Please note that you will have to adapt the constructor with the original block constructor.

Don't forget the usual `app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/module.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Vendor_Module" setup_version="0.0.1" />
</config>
```

As well as the `app/code/Vendor/Module/registration.php`

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Vendor_Module',
    __DIR__
);
```

Finally run the following commands:

```
php bin/magento module:enable Vendor_Module
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

And now you should be able to call the following in your template:

```
$attributes = $block->getAttributes($attributeSetId);
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It seems to get the attribute set information (like name, sort order and id), but what about the attributes assigned to that set? Thanks again!

Comment: @Jim sorry I missed that. I've updated the answer so you can retrieve the attributes ;)

Comment: Works perfectly. Do you happen to know a way to look up the label for the attribute? I thought it would be part of the attribute itself but I'm not seeing a function to getLabel or anything close to that.

Comment: @Jim hmmm I think eav doesn't let u do that. Feel free to post a new question I'll check it out

Comment: Just found it: `$data->getDefaultFrontendLabel()`. Thank for all your help!

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism i want to get the attributes from the single attribute group id please look at my question http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/146168/magento-2-how-do-i-get-attributes-of-a-specific-group-like-product-details