# How to get custom attributes of a given attribute set ID in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute

How to retrieve a list of custom attributes of a given attribute set ID in Magento 2,

The idea is like this,

```
$this->getCustomAttributes(10);
```

Then the method will return all custom attributes related to attribute set with ID of 10

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/116962/magento-2-get-attribute-set-by-id