# Magento 2: How do i get attributes of a specific group like 'product details'

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, customer-attribute

Hi I want to fetch the attributes of a specific group only. How can i filter the attributes.

**Code:**

```
$attrCodes = $block->getProductAttrData($pattr);
foreach($attrCodes as $attrCode)
{
    echo $attrCode->getDefaultFrontendLabel().'<br>';
    echo $attrCode->getAttributeCode().'<br>';
}
}
```

I want to filter the product details group attributes. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  protected $_groupCollection; 


  public function __construct(
        ......
        \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Group\CollectionFactory $_groupCollection
        .....

    ) {


        .....
        $this->_groupCollection = $_groupCollection;
        .....
    }
    .
    public function getAttributeGroupId($attributeSetId)
    {
         $groupCollection = $this->_groupCollection->create();
         $groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id',$attributeSetId);
         $groupCollection->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_name','Testing'); // here you can add your attribute code 
         return $groupCollection->getFirstItem(); 

    }
```

now in phtml file

```
    $groupid=$block->getAttributeGroupId($product->getAttributeSetId());
    $productAttributes=$product->getAttributes();
      foreach ($productAttributes as $attribute):
        if ($attribute->isInGroup($product->getAttributeSetId(), $groupid->getAttributeGroupId())):
            if($attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product)):
                echo $attribute->getFrontendLabel().' : '.$attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($product).'<br />';
            endif;
         endif;
      endforeach;
```